# After switching drive from USB enclosure to internal SATA, disk doesn't show data

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, external-hdd, gdisk

On Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS amd64.

I swapped a GPT partition, formatted with GParted with a single LUKS partition while connected with a USB 3.0 enclosure, to an internal SATA connection. After being moved into the case to a SATA connection, gdisk shows:

```
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: present
```

The disk presents as if just free space.

I vaguely recall seeing this before, but I don't move around storage very often and can't recall how to fix this or avoid the problem in future.

Comment: I ended up answering this to the best of my ability:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1426389/600024

Comment: I am glad that you recovered your data and shared your solution. Don't forget to accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green. You may have to wait a day. This will help others.

Comment: @user68186 I appreciate it! Marked accepted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something about the enclosure and the way it communicates seems to cause a mismatch in sector communication and/or how the partition table is interpreted.

Thankfully, the LUKS header is still present and can be located. In my case this is helpful because the LUKS partition took up the entire disk past its header, **so the following solution will not be helpful on its own for a disk with multiple partitions**.

```
$ sudo hexdump -C /dev/sdb | grep '  4c 55 4b 53 ba be'
00100000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |LUKS..........@.|
^C
```

***Ctrl+C** to break*.

If you find a header as I did above (in this example, "00100000") with LUKS at the end, convert that hexadecimal to decimal and then divide by 512 to find the sector.

```
$ perl -le 'print hex("00100000");'
1048576

$ perl -le 'print (( 1048576 / 512 ));'
2048
```

Then, using gdisk:

1. Create a new GPT partition table.
2. Create a new LUKS partition starting at that sector (in this example, 2048), ending at the end of the disk. In my case, the partition type was 8309 ("8309 Linux LUKS").

Unfortunately, it appears if the LUKS partition didn't end at the end of the disk, there is no specific way to determine where it ends and you'll need to take another route to recovery.

What's outlined above, though, was enough to recover the single LUKS partition with no data loss.

---

References:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/recovering-a-deleted-partition-table-of-a-luks-encrypted-flash-drive-4175606168/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280173